# Unit testing Solidity JS

Tags: javascript, solidity, truffle

I want to test these 3 different require in my mint function with Javascript.

```
function mint(uint256 _mintAmount) public payable {
    require(_mintAmount > 0, "need to mint at least 1 NFT");
    require(_mintAmount <= maxMintAmount, "max mint amount per session exceeded");
    require(supply + _mintAmount <= maxSupply, "max NFT limit exceeded");
```

I'm really new to testing so I tried something like this. obviously its wrong but how can I test that _mintAmount <= maxMintAmount in a function like this

```
it('mint amount', async () =>{
    _mintAmount > 0;
    _mintAmount <= maxMintAmount;
    supply + _mintAmount <= maxSupply;
})
```

Comment: We're going to need more details about your contract as well as your test script. You can refer to this doc: http://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/testing/writing-tests-in-javascript.html  If you still have issues, then update your question with more information

Answer (score 2):

ended up doing this,

since all the checks were already in my mint function. mint(0) would return "need to mint at least 1 NFT" so I used assert.equal() for that.  By using try/catch to get the revert error message I check for the expected output for any input that I want.

```
it('mint amount', async function () {
    try {
        await NFT.mint.sendTransaction(0);
    }
    catch (err) {
        assert.equal("need to mint at least 1 NFT", err.reason);
    }
});

it('mint amount2', async function () {
    try {
        await NFT.mint.sendTransaction(1);
    }
    catch (err) {
        assert.equal("max mint amount per session exceeded", err.reason);
    }
});

it('mint amount3', async function () {
    try {
        await NFT.mint.sendTransaction(2);
    }
    catch (err) {
        assert.equal("max NFT limit exceeded", err.reason);
    }
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).